# Enabling Fields on Sales Order Screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to enable fields on the Sales Order screen when the Status of the Sales Order is Completed.

I found a few other posts with solutions on older versions of Acumatica where you need to also change things in the Automation steps but in Version 21.207 Automation steps has been replaced with Workflows and I can't seem to edit them for the Sales Order screen.

My Code:

```
protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
    if (row == null) return;
    if (Condition1 != null && Condition2 == true)
    {     
        cache.AllowUpdate = true;
        Base.Document.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrder.salesPersonID>(cache, e.Row, true);
    }
}
```

The Old Posts:
[Enable SOLine field after Order Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213115/enable-soline-field-after-order-completed)
[How to enable CustomerOrderNbr field in Sales Order screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940261/how-to-enable-customerordernbr-field-in-sales-order-screen/)

**Update**
Tried the answer from
Kyle Vanderstoep

But unfortunately the `cache.AllowUpdate = true;` stays False after stepping over it in debugging mode.
[image: Debugging]

**Update 2**

The Solution from Kyle Vanderstoep did work in the end, after I remade the customization. Acumatica and my code was just acting up the first time round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps, override in workflow and in row selected. This one is for CustomerRefNbr

```
    public override void Configure(PXScreenConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var context = configuration.GetScreenConfigurationContext<SOOrderEntry, SOOrder>();
        context.UpdateScreenConfigurationFor(
            c => c.WithFlows(flowContainer =>
            {
                flowContainer
                    .Update(SOBehavior.SO, df => df
                        .WithFlowStates(fls =>
                        {
                            fls.Update<SOOrderStatus.completed>(flsc => flsc
                                .WithFieldStates(fs => fs.AddField<SOOrder.customerRefNbr>()));
                        }));
            }));
    }

    public virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseN)
    {
        baseN(cache, e);
        SOOrder doc = e.Row as SOOrder;

        if (doc == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        cache.AllowUpdate = true;
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOOrder.customerRefNbr>(cache, null, true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the Workflow, but unfortunately the row selected code to allow the field to be updated does not update the cache as expected, see update on the post.

Comment: Did you change the fields to the one you wanted in the workflow and test? That code is live and works on a customer site.

Comment: Your solution does work, but it only worked for me in a brand new customization. For some reason it failed to work even after I commented out all of my code in the first customization.